# Appstore occasionally fails to find app linked from mobile safari

Tags: iphone, safari, app-store

So having finished an app for a client, I've been asked to alert any users entering their website via iPhone/Safari that there's an app, and to ask the user if he/she would like to download it.

The method I'm using is to simply set window.location to "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/[appname]". No redirects, straight to the appstore. Ought to work great, at least judging by the absence of people with similar googlable problems, but it seems that every now and then the appstore gives me and some of my co-workers an "app not found" error screen.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? A solution would be delicious.

Comment: Have you tried using the App id instead of the name?

Comment: No, but as this only happens occasionally I'm not certain I could call that a "solution". I'd like to know the cause of the initial failure so that I can be sure.

Comment: Turns out that doesn't work at all by the way :P